# Check company name using a web service or something

Tags: c#, database, web-services

I have a c# destktop application. In my database i have the names for some companies. My problem is that not all the names are written correctly so i need something to check the company name. I have found online platforms for checking name and CUI company, but i dont know how to integrate in my application. Could you help me, please?

UPDATE:

```
<form name="codfiscalForm" method="POST" action="/numeCod.html">

                                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="text3">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                      <td width="33%">


                                        &nbsp;Judetul:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <!--webbot bot="Validation" s-display-name="cod" s-data-type="Number" s-number-separators="x," b-value-required="TRUE" i-minimum-length="1" i-maximum-length="10" s-validation-constraint="Greater than or equal to" s-validation-value="1" s-validation-constraint="Less than or equal to" s-validation-value="9999999999" -->


                                        <select name="judet" size="1" class="form2">

                                          <option value="40">BUCURESTI</option>

                                          <option value="01">ALBA</option>

                                          <option value="02">ARAD</option>

                                          <option value="03">ARGES</option>

                                          <option value="04">BACAU</option>

                                          <option value="05">BIHOR</option>

                                          <option value="06">BISTRITA-NASAUD</option>

                                          <option value="07">BOTOSANI</option>

                                          <option value="08">BRASOV</option>

                                          <option value="09">BRAILA</option>

                                          <option value="10">BUZAU</option>

                                          <option value="11">CARAS-SEVERIN</option>

                                          <option value="13">CONSTANTA</option>

                                          <option value="51">CALARASI</option>

                                          <option value="14">COVASNA</option>

                                          <option value="12">CLUJ</option>

                                          <option value="15">DIMBOVITA</option>

                                          <option value="16">DOLJ</option>

                                          <option value="17">GALATI</option>

                                          <option value="52">GIURGIU</option>

                                          <option value="18">GORJ</option>

                                          <option value="19">HARGHITA</option>

                                          <option value="20">HUNEDOARA</option>

                                          <option value="21">IALOMITA</option>

                                          <option value="23">ILFOV</option>

                                          <option value="22">IASI</option>

                                          <option value="24">MARAMURES</option>

                                          <option value="25">MEHEDINTI</option>

                                          <option value="26">MURES</option>

                                          <option value="27">NEAMT</option>

                                          <option value="28">OLT</option>

                                          <option value="29">PRAHOVA</option>

                                          <option value="30">SATU MARE</option>

                                          <option value="31">SALAJ</option>

                                          <option value="32">SIBIU</option>

                                          <option value="33">SUCEAVA</option>

                                          <option value="34">TELEORMAN</option>

                                          <option value="35">TIMIS</option>

                                          <option value="36">TULCEA</option>

                                          <option value="37">VASLUI</option>

                                          <option value="38">VALCEA</option>

                                          <option value="39">VRANCEA</option>
                                    </select>&nbsp;
                                      </td>
                                      <td width="29%">Numele:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <!--webbot bot="Validation" s-display-name="nume" s-data-type="String" b-allow-letters="TRUE" b-allow-digits="TRUE" b-allow-whitespace="TRUE" s-allow-other-chars=". , ? &quot; &quot;" b-value-required="TRUE" i-minimum-length="2" --> 
                                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form2" size="15">

</td>
                                      <td width="38%"><input name="submit" type="submit" class="form1" value="VIZUALIZARE"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="33%">
&nbsp;</td>
                                      <td width="29%">&nbsp;</td>
                                      <td width="38%">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="33%">
&nbsp;</td>
                                      <td width="67%" colspan="2"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody></table>

                               </form>
```

For example, i have this form for a post method. There are 2 inputs, one for company adress and one for company name. By clicking the button "vizualizeaza", it returns me companies after name. How can i integrate this in my desktop application

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific. What have you tried with which services? What couldn't you get to work? Is this for one county or many (companies exist within national boundaries).

Comment: How do those oonline platforms expose their services? If they are web services, they should provide the WSDL of those services and/or a API to consume those services. The way to integrate in your application depends on the way those platforms expose their functionality

Comment: My problem is that i dont know how to begin and what to search....My companies are from one country

Comment: "I have found online platforms for checking name and CUI company", which platform? That is being asked. Are they exposing rest apis for validation?

Comment: You question isn't clear. Try to ask specific and clear question.

Comment: Search for "[service name] API"